# Finding out ARC file entry point

Tags: ida, entry-point

I got dump from ci module and after deflate compressed data, this time I can't find the data I am looking for without disassembly it, sometimes I can extract data manually, but this time file is a bit different.

So I have tried to load file and test with 2 possible targets, ARCompact and ARCTangent, and loading address I tested with 0x0 and 0x400000, because I see some offsets in binary (L.E) like:

```
207B2A40
347B2A40
```

So I guess loading must be close to that offset but no successful, only got garbage fucntions.
The first 0xB0 data from file is like this:

```
4A2100004A2200004A2300004A240000
4A2500004A2600004A2700004A200010
4A2100104A2200104A2300104A240010
4A2500104A2600104A2700104A200020
4A2100204A2200204A2300204A240020
4A2500204A2600204A2700204A200030
4A2100304A2000002220800F23408009
0A24803F2B4048B80A22803F2B406059
0A22808F00000000E22082004A230030
2220800F2240DC9E090000006CD41640
692040004A2600704A2600704A260070
```

And these flags are before gzip header:

```
    48B82B40
    48B82B40
    00200300
    2E 6B65726E656C -> kernel
    0000000000
    004B5F40 -*
    004B5F40 -* Offset where kernel is decompressed?
    00400600 -> ?
    1F8B0800 -> gzip
```

Hope someone could help me in someway.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be ARCompact code:

```
CODE:00000000                 mov     r1, 0
CODE:00000004                 mov     r2, 0
CODE:00000008                 mov     r3, 0
CODE:0000000C                 mov     r4, 0
CODE:00000010                 mov     r5, 0
CODE:00000014                 mov     r6, 0
CODE:00000018                 mov     r7, 0
CODE:0000001C                 mov     r8, 0
CODE:00000020                 mov     r9, 0
CODE:00000024                 mov     r10, 0
CODE:00000028                 mov     r11, 0
CODE:0000002C                 mov     r12, 0
CODE:00000030                 mov     r13, 0
CODE:00000034                 mov     r14, 0
CODE:00000038                 mov     r15, 0
CODE:0000003C                 mov     r16, 0
CODE:00000040                 mov     r17, 0
CODE:00000044                 mov     r18, 0
CODE:00000048                 mov     r19, 0
CODE:0000004C                 mov     r20, 0
CODE:00000050                 mov     r21, 0
CODE:00000054                 mov     r22, 0
CODE:00000058                 mov     r23, 0
CODE:0000005C                 mov     r24, 0
CODE:00000060                 mov     r25, 0
CODE:00000064                 mov     r0, 0
CODE:00000068                 jl      0x40230980
CODE:00000070                 mov     sp, 0x402BB848
CODE:00000078                 mov     gp, 0x402B5960
CODE:00000080                 mov.f   r2, 0
CODE:00000088                 jlne    [r2]
CODE:0000008C                 mov     fp, 0
CODE:00000090                 jl      0x40229EDC
CODE:00000098                 b       loc_A0
```

The load base could be 40000000 or 40200000, but might be something else too.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have tried those base addresses and after press 'c' I get same result, but does not appear all functions, then I select all file and press 'c' again and functions seems to be garbage again. The offset I check for confirm the functions are ok is 0x00104968 in plain file, this offset is a 0x70 key that must be xored. Here is the file https://file.town/download/vwy508j3uyljbgybp3vtx8gqo

Comment: I found xor key offset, 0x00104968 ^ 0x00106170, at least it makes xor with this offset, need to find out entry point for check more coincidences...